# Button in CollectionView not appearing

Tags: ios, swift, button, collectionview

I want to create a button in my CollectionView Cell. But it doesn't show up. Are my constrains correct?

This is my code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    if let vc = cell.viewWithTag(111) {
       vc.backgroundColor = Colors[indexPath.row]
    }

    let nextButton = UIButton()
    nextButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    nextButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "gear"), for: .normal)
    nextButton.tintColor = UIColor.black
    nextButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    nextButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    nextButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    view.addSubview(nextButton)
    nextButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    nextButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true


    return cell
}

@IBAction func editButtonTapped() -> Void {
    print("Hello Edit Button")
}
```

Comment: Did you try giving a different backgroundColor?

Comment: I think you have to add button in the cell as `cell.addSubview(nextButton)` and it's better to add button inside collection view cell rather in `cellForRowAt`

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing this? Just add it via storyboard? `CellForRowAt` will get called multiple times and add a button and constraints (possibly why it doesn't work) repeatedly. If you are doing everything programatically you should consider adding constraints in the `init` method.

I can't find anything wrong with the constraints. Just try and change the place where you add them.

Additionally to debug your view layout consider using `Debug View Hierarchy` in Xcode to see if the button is being added correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of view add it in cell contentView...

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        if let vc = cell.viewWithTag(111) {
           vc.backgroundColor = Colors[indexPath.row]
        }

        let nextButton = UIButton()
        nextButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        nextButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "gear"), for: .normal)
        nextButton.tintColor = UIColor.black
        nextButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        nextButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        nextButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        cell.contentView.addSubview(nextButton)
        nextButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        nextButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true


        return cell
    }
```

But its not a good approach to add button in cellForRow ... you should have a custom cell class .. Add this button in custom class init method

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be adding the button to the `UIViewController`'s `view` instead of the `cell`. I've made corrections and made your code working on Xcode-playground. I'll post it here and try it out on your play-ground and check for yourself how it works.

```swift
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        30
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = .red

        let nextButton = UIButton()
        nextButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        nextButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "gear"), for: .normal)
        nextButton.tintColor = UIColor.black
        nextButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        nextButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        nextButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        cell.addSubview(nextButton)
        nextButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        nextButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        return cell
    }

    @IBAction func editButtonTapped() -> Void {
        print("Hello Edit Button")
    }

}

let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 150, height: 150)
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ViewController(collectionViewLayout: layout))
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```